# Reading php comments using php page that open text files, CTF

Tags: php, vulnerability

There is a CTF Problem that it needs to see comments of a PHP file using some vulnerabilities of PHP; The Question is:
In the link bellow You must change `lorem.php` to read exact php comments of `index.php` file
[http://web.ringzer0team.com:13371/index.php?page=lorem.php](http://ctf:Vb48Uj2SsvEYwm783MuKRj91serv@web.ringzer0team.com:13371/index.php?page=lorem.php)

I have tried `index.php` but it makes a infinite loop. And I now the permissions is wrong; e.g. `/etc/passwd` will show the `passwd` file and the flag in `/etc/passwd` is for another challenge

Comment: Welcome to Information Security. Are you asking how to solve the CTF problem? Can you show what you have tried and narrow your question a little? The community is less responsive if it feels like you are asking for all the work to be done for you.

Comment: I'd like to answer this question because this was a lot of fun to solve and I didn't know about this technique until you posted the question. But, I want to respect the game that ringzer0team has set up. The [challenge](http://ringzer0team.com/challenges/76) provides an option to "purchase" a hint, if you want to go that route. I searched online and couldn't find a writeup, and I don't want to make the first public one. If you can make a question that isn't related to a specific CTF problem, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: To see such samples we need a server that can load php sample. And I don't have one.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter a local file inclusion (LFI) vulnerability there is a special technique that enables you to read files from the target system by making use of a PHP wrapper. This will not work in every case but you might want to give it a try.

You can read more about the PHP wrapper on the official php.net site:
http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

This technique basically lets you use PHPs input and output streams as well as apply different filters to them.  (http://php.net/manual/en/filters.php)

To read a resource you can use a payload in the form of:

```
php://filter/resource=/some/dir/secretfile.php

php://filter/resource=anothersecretfile.php
```

To apply a filter replace *filtername* with the name of the filter:

```
php://filter/filtername/resource=anothersecretfile.php
```

In some cases there will be errors depending on the specific implementation and surroundings of the LFI.
A good way do handle these can be to convert the output in a way that will not be interpreted by the target server.

On filter you might want to look at is the

```
convert.base64-encode
```

filter that converts the stream data to base64.